# Linq join using split in condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm a newcomer in Linq C#.
I have a scenario where I need to check part of a sentence is equal to another value of the field.
I use IndexOf to get part of the sentence in the left join condition. The result is good when any data match between 'a' and 'c'. But when data does not exist in 'c', then the value of 'test' is all data of table `dbData.Data3`.

Can anyone know what I'm missing here?

```
                    var test = (from a in dbData.Data2
                                let COLODescIndexOfSpace = a.LongKeywordDesc .IndexOf(' ') < 0 ? 0 : a.LongKeywordDesc .IndexOf(' ')
                                join c in dbData.Data3 on
                                new
                               {
                                   KeywordDesc = a.LongKeywordDesc .Substring(0, COLODescIndexOfSpace),
                                   Stsrc = true
                               }
                               equals new
                               {
                                   KeywordDesc = c.KeywordDesc,
                                   Stsrc = (c.Stsrc != AppConstant.StrSc.Deactive)
                               }
                            into c_leftjoin
                            from c in c_leftjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where lmsCourseOutlineIds.Contains(a.CourseOutlineID)
                            select new
                            {
                                data = a.KeywordID,
                                data2 = c.KeywordID,
                                data3 = c.KeywordDesc,
                            }).ToList();
```

this is some example of data
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ajv4.png)

and this is what I expect as result
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcnQ3.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific about this: "I have scenario where I need to check part of a sentence is equals to another value of field." What part of a sentence? What other value? What field? An example might be helpful. What is the result you want from your query?

Comment: hi @topsail I have added some data sample and what result that I expected. I want to left join 2 table using linq .Currently I use substring and indexOf on the condition. But result is not as I expect.

Comment: Okay copy that sample data as text into the question - images are always second best at stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: What is the match you are looking for? For instance, `try not to disturb` starts with `try` - is the match you are testing that the sentence starts with a keyword?

Comment: also btw I am probably going to throw up my hands on this one eventually ... but I hope we can get as far as a good definition of the problem. It would be nice to know what your goal is and why you are doing this? For instance, how many keywords do you have, how many sentences do you have? This is not where sql shines, this type of text processing... (and hence, by extension, not going to be great Linq either - is this data in a database? Or is this data in memory in Lists? Some other data structure? I just assume sql because that's my home turf).

Comment: Hi @topsail, yes correct. And as you can see because line 2 doesn't start with "try" and "about", then KeywordDesc and AdditionalInfo should be null.

Comment: how many keywords do you have (or expect to have in 5 years time?). How many sentences do you have (or expect to have in 5 years time?)

Comment: Hi @topsail, all data is from sql, from 2 different tables. Each table contain around 1000+ data right now.

Comment: As I predicted, I throw in the towel on a complicated linq query :) But I have a solution where you created a view in your db and use the view ... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem (I will leave it to my Linq betters figure out a solution purely with Linq). In short, just create a SQL View in the database and call it to get your desired results.

For example, in the database:

```
create view dbo.GetSentencesByKeywords
as
select 
    d2.ID,
    d2.longKeywordDesc,
    d3.keywordDesc,
    d3.AdditionalInfo
from 
    dbo.Data2 d2
    left join
    (
        select 
            ID, 
            keyWordDesc, 
            AdditionalInfo, 
            len(keyWordDesc) as keyWordLength 
        from dbo.Data3 data3
    ) d3
    on substring(d2.longKeywordDesc, 0, d3.keyWordLength + 1) = d3.keywordDesc
```

Now the linq is nice and simple (assuming you can re-scaffold the dbContext to add it to your models, or otherwise can get it in there one way or another):

`var x = dbData.GetSentencesByKeywords.Select(c => c);`